# Forum posts not showing

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a really big problem here with alot of code but i think i know the problem
When im creating a topic(post) it get the category_id of 0 but category_id's is starting on 1 so the topic(post) is not showing in enny of the categorys. But i dont know how to fix that problem.

My codes:

- index.php:  **pastebin.com/5sBNtur7**
- login_parse.php:  **pastebin.com/WnYv4caK**
- logout_parse.php:  **pastebin.com/2eW5VWn8**
- view_category.php:  **pastebin.com/PCAHv0pe**
- create_topic.php:  **pastebin.com/LU7Ua42z**
- create_topic_parse.php:  **pastebin.com/DeUqX4ju**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your create_topic.php on line 33

```
<input type="hidden" name="cid" value"<?php echo $cid; ?>" />
```

Your are missing the "="

```
<input type="hidden" name="cid" value="<?php echo $cid; ?>" />
```

Comment: You are the best! :D tnx!